# How to create Events in Google Calendar API with Android

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I´m trying to insert some events in my Google Calendar with Android. For reading the calendar, there is a quickstart tutorial for Android on the Googles developer page and it works fine. But there is no Android code example for inserting events, I just found an Java code example:

```
    Event event = new Event()
            .setSummary("Google I/O 2015")
            .setLocation("800 Howard St., San Francisco, CA 94103")
            .setDescription("A chance to hear more about Google's developer products.");

    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T09:00:00-07:00");
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    event.setStart(start);

    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2015-05-28T17:00:00-07:00");
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("America/Los_Angeles");
    event.setEnd(end);

    String calendarId = "primary";
    event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());
```

The problem: 'cannot resolve symbol 'service''. Is there a possibility to import 'service', so I can use the Java Code for inserting Events with Android or do I have to use a completly other way for creating events?

Link to Googles introduction for creating events: https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/create-events

Comment: Did you include the packages com.google.api.services.calendar
com.google.api.services.calendar.model in your code? you can also check sample java codes here https://developers.google.com/api-client-library/java/apis/calendar/v3 .Also, check this link for android code http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#intent-insert

Comment: If you used the quickstart as your basis then service is called mService. Try replacing it everywhere ;)

Comment: @SGC Yes, I included the packages and also imported the jar´s, like suggested in your first link. I have also checked your second link before and tried it, the problem here is the code is made for the local Android Calendar Application, so I can create events for this calendar, but dont know how to change the code so I can create events for the Google calendar.

Comment: @luc : "Cannot resolve symbol mService"

Comment: I propose you post your entire code.

Comment: Edit (was not possible to change my comment anymore -.-)@luc : I looked it up in my MainActivity, there was a variable named mService and the type was com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar ... okay, so i solved the problem with the "Cannot resolve symbol mService", it´s still not working, but at least I took a step forward, Thank you :)

Comment: Cool, thanks for letting me know! :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm really late to this question. I don't know if you have already found a way. But i'm just going to try to give a solution to this. If you have read the documentation and setup the class of Calendar Activity then you should have already got the `mCredential` object initialized with permissions which are required. Then all you have to do is call that simple java code which was provided to create an event. I'm providing a sample method to do that:

```
public void createEvent(GoogleAccountCredential mCredential) {

    HttpTransport transport = AndroidHttp.newCompatibleTransport();
    JsonFactory jsonFactory = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();
    com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar service = new com.google.api.services.calendar.Calendar.Builder(
            transport, jsonFactory, mCredential)
            .setApplicationName("R_D_Location Callendar")
            .build();


    Event event = new Event()
            .setSummary("Event- April 2016")
            .setLocation("Dhaka")
            .setDescription("New Event 1");

    DateTime startDateTime = new DateTime("2016-04-17T18:10:00+06:00");
    EventDateTime start = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(startDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
    event.setStart(start);

    DateTime endDateTime = new DateTime("2016-04-17T18:40:00+06:00");
    EventDateTime end = new EventDateTime()
            .setDateTime(endDateTime)
            .setTimeZone("Asia/Dhaka");
    event.setEnd(end);

    String[] recurrence = new String[]{"RRULE:FREQ=DAILY;COUNT=2"};
    event.setRecurrence(Arrays.asList(recurrence));

    EventAttendee[] attendees = new EventAttendee[]{
            new EventAttendee().setEmail("abir@aksdj.com"),
            new EventAttendee().setEmail("asdasd@andlk.com"),
    };
    event.setAttendees(Arrays.asList(attendees));

    EventReminder[] reminderOverrides = new EventReminder[]{
            new EventReminder().setMethod("email").setMinutes(24 * 60),
            new EventReminder().setMethod("popup").setMinutes(10),
    };
    Event.Reminders reminders = new Event.Reminders()
            .setUseDefault(false)
            .setOverrides(Arrays.asList(reminderOverrides));
    event.setReminders(reminders);

    String calendarId = "primary";
    try {
        event = service.events().insert(calendarId, event).execute();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    System.out.printf("Event created: %s\n", event.getHtmlLink());

}
```

And another thing is that you have to call this method through an AsyncTask. Cause creating an event is a background process. And i hope this method also clears you problem of  *cannot resolve symbol service*.

Comment: A late answer is better than no answer, thank you. I don´t need it anymore, but maybe it will help other people.

Comment: can you help me here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36885407/adding-events-for-all-days-between-start-date-and-end-date-in-google-calendar-an